# Posix classes in regex module Python

Tags: python, regex

I installed the module [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) (not `re`!) for Python 3.4.3 solely to be able to use POSIX classes such as `[:graph:]`. However, these don't seem to work.

```
import regex

sentence = "I like math, I divided ÷ the power ³ by ¾"

sentence = regex.sub("[^[:graph:]\s]","",sentence)

print(sentence)
```

Output: `I like math, I divided ÷ the power ³ by ¾`

Expected output: `I like math, I divided  the power  by`

It does work in [PCRE](https://regex101.com/r/oN8aD4/1) though. So what am I missing here?

Comment: Try `sentence = regex.sub(r"(?V1)[^[:graph:]\s]","",sentence)`.

Comment: @stribizhev Same output unfortunately.

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes Doesn't work either.

Comment: If anything, I think it's PCRE that's doing it wrong.  `[:graph:]` is supposed to match any visible character, but PCRE is only counting ASCII characters.  The `regex` library treats the POSIX character classes as fully Unicode-aware, except a few that seem to be limited to the original POSIX definitions. (Search for "POSIX character classes" at the link you provided.)

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes I don't think that would work anyway, because I want to target all elements that are nor graph, nor \s.

Comment: It works for me on python2.7 on windows (using ```regex```, not ```re```) [Checking on python3 now]

Comment: It doesn't work in python3, my guess would be it is because of the change in unicode handling. I support Alan's comment

Comment: @vks Indeed, your comment works best. Can you post it as an answer? I'd gladly accept.

Comment: @vks Upvoted and accepted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `sentence = regex.sub("[^[:graph:]\s]","",sentence,flags=regex.VERSION1)`

You need to add `flag` `regex.VERSION1`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the `regex` module, but you can get the result with

```
import re

sentence = "I like math, I divided ÷ the power ³ by ¾"

sentence = re.sub("[^\x21-\x7E\s]","",sentence)

print(sentence)
```

There is a nice graph at http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html that shows how to convert the POSIX classes to ASCII, which the `re` module understands.

Comment: I'm late, but this doesn't work as expected. It also deletes special characters such as é and à which I don't want.

Comment: Just to let you know, that doesn't solve the problem either when the characters is surrounded by spaces: https://regex101.com/r/sM0yO2/1. I'm guessing that the ASCII range doesn't include special letter characters.

Comment: @BramVanroy:  I've been playing around with this some more.  Can you explain how `[^\x21-\x7E\s]`is behaving differently than `[^[:graph:]\s]` for you.  For me, both are removing é and à.  When I moved the `\s` outside the square brackets it stopped deleting them only because I was typing them at the end of the string I was testing. https://regex101.com/r/sM0yO2/2 and https://regex101.com/r/sM0yO2/3

Comment: In R, *with the unicode flag* they behave differently though. At least, that's how I tested it. If I got the time, I'll post a test case for you.